interactions in non-negative least squares
In the context of regressions models, I have some features for which I have a prior view on the coefficient sign while others may not be useful on their own (expect small or zero coefficient and no view on the coefficient sign) but could be useful as interaction.
With linear models, I'm thinking of handling this with Non-Negative Least Squares as follows: for each pair of signed feature $f$ and interaction feature $g$, I split $g$ into eg 3 indicators $1_{0<g<0.2}$, $1_{0.2<g<0.8}$ and $1_{0.8<g<1}$ and generate 3 features as the product between $f$ and these indicators. So I fit NNLS with $3nk$ features where $n$ is the number of signed features and $k$ of interaction features.
What is the name of this kind of situation mixing signed features and interactions? What's a good reference textbook for this kind of modelling?

First, binning a continuous predictor is not a good idea. You shouldn't break up your g variable that way.
Second, non-negative least squares makes sense if the regression coefficients can't possibly take on negative values. If non-negativity of coefficients is just your "prior view" without a solid theoretical basis, however, I'd be reluctant to recommend it. I've been fooled too many times by Mother Nature disagreeing with my preconceptions. If you are working with Bayesian approaches you could use a prior that corresponds to your "prior view" but you should be open to the possibility that your "prior view" is incorrect.

In general yes - binning a continuous is loss of information. But in this case, how else would you "condition" the features by the interaction term, for which there is no prior view on the coefficient? I use NNLS because the coefficients have a known sign and it's a very low signal-to-noise problem so enforcing constraints is critical.
